# Searching the same value to display only one value using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the data as below:

```
maly chantha maly chantha
```

I want to get only: `maly chantha`

How should I do?

Comment: You have an array with 4 elements, and you want to get the last two? Can you give the surrounding code - what's the array called etc? Do you want to pop them off the end, just read them? Always the last two, or does it vary? Need a little more info / code / context.

Comment: I think he just wants unique entries, but yes, more information and code are definitely needed.

Comment: Is that data in another file? Is it in the same file as a string or an array?

Comment: @andrewsi - thanks. Makes sense. Easy answer, then...

Comment: it is an array.I mean that the array element have the same value but I want to search it, if it the same I will take only one value.

Answer (score 4):

You could use array_unique() http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php if you want the unique values from an array.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). It removes duplicates from an array.

Example:

```
<?php
$array = array('one', 'two', 'one', 'two');
$array = array_unique($array);
var_dump($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array and save the unique values.

```
$str = "maly chantha maly chantha";

$input_arr = explode(" ", $str);

$final_arr = array_unique($input_arr);
```

Comment: well then you just need the last line